# Rate google places in android

Tags: android, google-places-api

Hi friends i am working on an android application that have the different types of places like resturant hospital and other and almost we have done this but the issue is that my client want to rate the places through the application. Secondly he want to upload some images on some places where we donot have the json of the picture.

Is there is any way to rate the google places and get back there rating in there json response also how can we upload the place image. and get back there image json through the google api services?

Any help will be appreciated thank you :)